# I want to search data from a csv file, but its not working

Tags: javascript, html, csv

This HTML is meant to link an input to a .csv file. So for example, lets say I enter in the value '1' for the gameID, all the relevant information about that game should pop up, but it doesn't. Heres my code, I'm clueless as to what may be wrong, any help would be greatly appreciated. Also heres a link to an image of the csv file, incase the csv file is the culprit

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Games Library Reservations Page</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<body background="white">
<div id='main'>

    <div id='titleImage'><img title='Home' src='GLLogo2.png' width='700' height='190' alt='Games Lending Library' /></div>
    <div id='menu-wrapper'>
        <div id='menu'>
            <ul>
                <li><a href='test.html'>Home</a></li>
                <li class='current_page_item'><a href='#'>Reservations</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h1>Reservations</h1>
    </div>

    <form name="theForm" onsubmit="return validation();">
    Your name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="theName" required>
    <br>

    Game ID:<br>
    <input type="number" id="gameId" onchange="getGameName()" min="1" required>
    <input type="text" id="gameName" readonly>
    <br>

    Reservation Start Date:<br>
    <input type="date" name="startDate" required><div id="dateWarn"></div>
    <br>

    Days Reserved:<br>
    <input type="number" name="days" id="days" onchange="calculate()" min="1" max="5" required>
    <br>

    Total Cost:<br>
    <input type="text" id="totalCost" readonly>
    <br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript"
    function calculate() {
    var theDays = document.getElementById('days').value;
    var theGameId = document.getElementById('gameId').value;
    var valueField=document.getElementById('totalCost');
    var totalValue;
    var gamePrice=document.getElementById("dataTable").rows[theGameId].cells[8].innerHTML;
    totalValue=theDays*gamePrice;
    valueField.value="£"+totalValue.toFixed(2);
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"
fucntion validation() {
    var theGameId = document.getElementById('gameId').value;
    var rentalDays=document.getElementById("dataTable").rows[theGameId].cells[8].innerHTML;
    var theDays = document.getElementById('days').value;
    if(theDays>rentalDays){
        alert ("Failed to submit form. The number of days entered exceeds the maximum amount of days available to reserved the choosen game");
        return false;
    }else{
        alert("Form submitted succesfully!");
        return true;
    }
}
</script>

<script src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.min.js"</script>

        <script type="text/javasctipt"charset="utf-8">
            d3.text("games.csv", fucntion(data) {
                var parsedCSV = d3.csv.parseRows(data);

                var conatiner = d3.select("body")
                    .append("table")
                    .attr("id","dataTable")
                    .attr("style","display:none")

                    .selectAll("tr")
                        .data(parsedCSV).enter()
                        .append("tr")

                    .selectAll("td")
                        .data(fucntion(d) { return d; }).enter()
                        .append("td")
                        .text(function(d) { return d; });
            });
        </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
fucntion getGameName() {
        var theGameName=document.getElementById("gameName");
        var theID = document.getElementById("gameId").value;
        var maxVal=document.getElementById("dataTable").rows.length-1;
        if(theId>maxVal) {
            theGameName.value="ID not valid";
            theGameName.style.backgroundColor="red"
            theGameName.style.color="white"
        }else{
            var tableValue=document.getElementById("dataTable").rows[theID].cells[8].innerHTML;
            theGameName.value=tableValue;
            theGameName.style.backgroundColor="#7CFC00"
            theGameName.style.color="black"
        }
        calculate();
}
</script>
</div>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: `but it doesn't` ... could you supply some actual information? what do you expect? what do you observe? any output on the browser developer tools console?

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite a novice. So on the html page their are input boxes;

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" function calculate()` ... well, that's wrong for a start ... developer tools console output would show you this ... if you want to develop web pages, use developer tools

Comment: So there are input boxes, your name, gameID, reservation date days reserved and total cost. In the your name box you simply enter in your name. In the GameID box you enter in the id of the game you want(1, 2 etc) then beside the gameID input box theirs another input which is read only which should say the name of the game associated with the gameID. This is where the csv file comes in, the html code should grab theinformation from the csv file. Also on days reserved you enter in a day and it should multiply the number of days by the price of the game listed in the csv file.

Comment: fix the basics first, like malformed tags etc